# AngularJS - Reusing HTML template code without AJAX call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have an Angular app which displays "cards" (think Google cards) in two columns.  Because of this I end up with HTML looking a little like

```
<div class="leftColumn">
    <div ng-repeat="module in Modules">
        <span>{{module.UpTime.TotalTime}}</span>

        <h2>{{module.ModuleName}}</h2>
        ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="rightColumn">
    <!-- I want the template here too :) -->
</div>
```

How can I write the template code within `leftColumn` only once such that it can be used in both `leftColumn` and `rightColumn`.  Note I realise this can be done with `ng-include` but why does this have to be a separate file, what if I want to specify the template within my current HTML page?

Comment: may be like https://gist.github.com/whisher/0dc3f28d89cfc2a9b875 yes I've cheated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) on how to embed multiple templates within a single page. Then just use `ng-include` and they will be loaded from local cache without any remote calls.

---

And to make it easier, here's a [code sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogXBZx) for you:

```
<!-- include this somewhere inside the element with `ng-app` attribute ... -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
    <div ng-repeat="module in Modules">...</div>
</script>

<!-- ... and then use the template as you would a remote one -->
<div class="leftColumn" ng-include="'/tpl.html'"></div>
<div class="rightColumn" ng-include="'/tpl.html'"></div>
```

Keep in mind that using `<script>` this way means compiling it as an AngularJS directive, so **it must be inside the element with `ng-app` attribute**.

Comment: I dont want to include it via an external HTML page!

Comment: Have you read the part of my answer where it says _"include multiple templates within a single page"_? (I'll change it to say _"embed"_, then.) Did you look at the linked documentation?

Comment: How do I do this without the click? Im trying to get it to just work statically but its not playing ball, it keeps trying to load `/tpl.html` - Ive copied your code but it still does this

Comment: See this [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogXBZx). Your `<script type="text/ng-template">` is an AngularJS directive, so it must NOT be outside your `ng-app` element.